# Memory required on NameNode for replicas in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html#concept_tdh_vj4_55) Cloudera blog post, in the `Replication` section, it has been explained that replication does not consume memory on the NameNode. However, I am skeptical about this because I understand that the NameNode stores information about each file, as well as its replicas, in main memory. How, then, is the memory requirement the same with or without replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well memory consumption depends on what you mean, because there is **physical memory** and **virtual memory** (I am talking about Namenode only here)

In terms of **physical memory**, the Cloudera blog is correct, as the it is responsibility of the Datanode to communicate to the Namenode (when connect after restart for example) what blocks it maintains. The Namenode is storing solely the file-system structure to the disk (fsimage and edits files).

Now the situation is slightly different when you are talking about **virtual memory**, where you can clearly see from the source code that `FSNamesystem` (which is the component responsible for maintaining the FS structure in RAM), has a reference to `BlockManager`. `BlockManager` by itself maintains the reference to `BlocksMap`, which according to documentation does maintain the list of datanodes with respective blocks.

> This class maintains the map from a block to its metadata. block's
>   metadata currently includes blockCollection it belongs to and the
>   datanodes that store the block.

If you go through the source code of the `BlockManager` you can clearly see what and where the `BlocksMap` is being used.

What actually comes to my mind, because Cloudera guys have experience in large scale computations and probably measured the impact, is that the size of this structure is not significant in comparison to the rest of the metadata the Namenode must be taking care of.